# What is the symbol of this component of a Battery Management System?

Tags: batteries, schematics, bms

I am studying about Battery Management Systems and currently in the phase of analyzing open-source projects to relate theory and practice (circuits in PCB design).

I found this [open-source BMS repo](https://github.com/ceech/BQ76920-BMS) and the schematic has a component which has no name label identifier (only T1):

[image]

Does anybody know what that component is? It seems like it receives the VCC voltage on the Vin and Vin_1 terminals and then it gives a Vout of which I don't know if it is the same voltage as VCC, but that voltage goes to the BQ76920 battery monitor chip.

Here is the part of the schematic (the text next to REGOUT's label says 3.3 V as output, so the T1 component could be a kind of voltage regulator):

[image]

What do you think that component could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That output is called "regout". So it's really probably a voltage regulator. And a 3.3V at that.

At your favourite electronic distributor you will find a lot of these. You probably don't need anything fancy – less than 1.7V dropout voltage should be standard for any LDO, including the cheapish xx1117.